# How do I find the device name assigned to USB thumb drive?

Tags: usb, mount

I am having some trouble mounting USB thumb drives in elementary.  When I insert a thumb drive, it does not automount (I understand that this is not supported in elementary).

When I look for the device to mount it, I can see the following:

dmesg :

```
[63954.021157] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[63954.166776] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0930, idProduct=6545
[63954.166777] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[63954.166778] usb 1-1: Product: DataTraveler 2.0
[63954.166778] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Kingston
[63954.166779] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: C8600088614CEF403A102EB2
[63954.167491] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[63954.167728] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
```

lsusb :

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:24a1 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e301 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:6713 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 0930:6545 Toshiba Corp. Kingston DataTraveler 102/2.0 / HEMA Flash Drive 2 GB / PNY Attache 4GB Stick
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

mount :

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=16364952k,nr_inodes=4091238,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=3278444k,mode=755)
/dev/mapper/elementary--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=37,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=16491)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on /boot type ext2 (rw,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr,acl)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=3278444k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
/home/.ecryptfs/user/.Private on /home/user type ecryptfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=08480028212d3846,ecryptfs_sig=x,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,relatime)
```

tailing /var/log/syslog I see the following when re-inserting:

```
Apr  3 12:43:56 XPS-15-9560 kernel: [64285.052423] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
Apr  3 12:43:56 XPS-15-9560 kernel: [64285.198345] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0930, idProduct=6545
Apr  3 12:43:56 XPS-15-9560 kernel: [64285.198347] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Apr  3 12:43:56 XPS-15-9560 kernel: [64285.198347] usb 1-1: Product: DataTraveler 2.0
Apr  3 12:43:56 XPS-15-9560 kernel: [64285.198348] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Kingston
Apr  3 12:43:56 XPS-15-9560 kernel: [64285.198349] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: C8600088614CEF403A102EB2
Apr  3 12:43:56 XPS-15-9560 kernel: [64285.199188] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Apr  3 12:43:56 XPS-15-9560 kernel: [64285.199333] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
Apr  3 12:43:56 XPS-15-9560 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 19: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1"
Apr  3 12:43:56 XPS-15-9560 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 19 was not an MTP device
```

From /var/log/kern.log:

```
Apr  3 12:43:56 XPS-15-9560 kernel: [64285.052423] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
Apr  3 12:43:56 XPS-15-9560 kernel: [64285.198345] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0930, idProduct=6545
Apr  3 12:43:56 XPS-15-9560 kernel: [64285.198347] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Apr  3 12:43:56 XPS-15-9560 kernel: [64285.198347] usb 1-1: Product: DataTraveler 2.0
Apr  3 12:43:56 XPS-15-9560 kernel: [64285.198348] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Kingston
Apr  3 12:43:56 XPS-15-9560 kernel: [64285.198349] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: C8600088614CEF403A102EB2
Apr  3 12:43:56 XPS-15-9560 kernel: [64285.199188] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Apr  3 12:43:56 XPS-15-9560 kernel: [64285.199333] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
```

Can I perhaps find the device name somewhere in here:
`/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1` ?
I have looked in there, but it just looks like a mess of files and directories to me.

I did try installing usbmount as several posters here had suggested, but it does not mount the device either.  I have tried 2 different thumb drives with different formats.  They both work fine on both of my Macs as well.  I am at a loss...

Comment: It should show up in `dmesg` output, something like this https://pastebin.com/F8tX6eXW. In this case it's `/dev/sdc1` and `/dev/sdc2`. You can mount it with `udisks --mount /dev/sdc1` or `udisks --mount /dev/sdc2`.

Comment: Hi, my dmesg output does not show anything after the "scsi host2:" line, unlike your pastebin example.  That is what is confusing me.

Comment: I've just installed `elementary` in `Virtualbox` and I see that `dmesg -w` correctly shows `sdb: sdb1 sdb2`. You can also check `ls -Al /dev/disk/by-id`

Comment: Devices are created by `udev` so maybe you have some strange `udev` rules? There is a mention of `mtp` in the log you posted.

Comment: This is a fresh install that I've done very little to, so I'm not sure how any changes would have been made to udev, but following that path I checked with udevadm

Comment: Seems it is instantly removing the device:
https://pastebin.com/DS8PZw3j

Comment: Check what you have in `/etc/udev/rules.d`. There might be rule that removes `usb` device. Try `udevadm test $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/bus/usb/001/018)` as shown by `Bus 001 Device 018: ID 0930:6545 Toshiba Corp. Kingston DataTraveler 102/2.0 / HEMA Flash Drive 2 GB / PNY Attache 4GB Stick`

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't have any rules in rules.d.  Out of frustration I rebooted again and the device shows up.  I hope it's a regularly occurring problem.

Comment: Hmm, it's possible that you did something you didn't understand or did something inadvertently or that it's a hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sav,

I too am a fellow Macintosh / elementary OS (Juno) user.  Other than using a Patriot Memory USB drive (which mounts consistently automatically) I may have one other suggestion for you.

```
GNOME Disks
```

This application can be installed through AppCenter.  It has the "look and feel" of Apple's Disk Utility program.  The only thing you will need to wrap your head around is the following:
*Stop button* will unmount the drive in question.
*Play button* will mount the drive in question.
*Minus button* will delete the partition (careful).
*Gears button* will format, resize, edit or benchmark the drive for you.

Hope that helps!